# Writing a generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I have a simple function

```
public static int Search(List<int> list, int item){}
```

I want to write it as generic function. Also I want to pass both List and Array, so can I write similar like this ?

```
public static T Search<S,T>(S list, T item) where T : IComparable & where S : IEnumerable<T> {}
```

Comment: Why not try it and see if it works?

Comment: Your signature looks reasonable .... **What is the question here?**

Comment: @GeorgeT Its not working, syntax error.

Comment: @Arnab You have a `&` between `IComparable` and `where`, remove it.

Comment: @Arnab if you have a syntax error include this in your question please

Comment: @Candide I want to pass both List and Array, then what should be the correct syntax ?

Comment: BTW a more reasonable thing for a generic search is something like `Option<T> TryFindFirst<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T,bool> predicate)`

Comment: ... and of course this (almost) already exists ... `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate syntax error is the `&`, change it to:

```
public static T Search<S,T>(S list, T item) 
  where T : IComparable 
  where S : IEnumerable<T> {}
```

Both lists and arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>` so you can get rid of the `S` type altogether:

```
public static T Search<T>(IEnuermable<T> list, T item) where T : IComparable
{}
```

Since you already state that in the `where` statement, these two are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
int Search<T> (IEnumerable<T> list, T item)
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to return a `T` ... more likely the Index

Comment: @AD.Net I want to pass both list and array.

Comment: @CarstenKönig, yes the index makes more sense, so updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for syntax?

```
    public static T Search<S,T>(S list, T item) where T : IComparable where S : IEnumerable<T> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also I want to pass both List and Array, so can I write similar like this ?

If you want to pass both `Array` and `List` to your function, then you need to find a common type that both `Array` and `List<T>` implements which could be an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static T Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
```